# C Code compiled failed in Linux Debian

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct

I'm currently writing C program, I'm using struct and pointer in the functions. Everything works well in Windows, but not linux debian. I'm having some errors when I try to compile my program in Linux Debian.

```
typedef struct human
{
char name[100],code[100];
}human;

void hello(char* name, char* code)
{}

int main()
{
human human;
hello(&human.name,&human.code);
return 0; 
}
```

I get those warning when compiling the main.c file:

> ```
> Warning passing argument 1 of Human from incompatible pointer type
> Note: expected char *a but argument is type of char(*)[100]
> Warning passing argument 2 of Human from incompatible pointer type
> Note: expected char *a but argument is type of char(*)[100]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct human
{
    char name[100], code[100];
} human;

void hello(char* name, char* code)
{
}

int main()
{
    human human;
    hello(human.name, human.code);
    return 0; 
}
```

Remove the ampersands (`&`) when passing the `name` and `code` arrays. A `char` array is compatible with `char*`.  When you say `human.name`, you're really referring to the address of the first element in the array.

Also, if `hello` doesn't return anything, its return type should be `void`. If you omit the return type, `int` is assumed, but this is a very old practice, and highly discouraged.

You should *always* use at least `-Wall` when compiling with GCC.  Best practice (which you should get used to sooner rather than later) is:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror foo.c
```

Finally, use proper indentation!

Answer (score 0):

The error basically means that you are passing address of an array to a function which expects a `char` array.

The type of `human.name` is `char [100]` i.e. `char` array of size 100. When you pass it as `human.name` to the function, it decays into base address of that array which has type `char*`. So, everything fine, and you actually wanted this behavior only.

Now, you tried to pass `&human.name`, which means you are trying to pass address of `human.name` array to the function, which is of type `char (*) [100]` (a pointer to `char` array of size 100), and hence the type mismatch occurs.